Is there a way to prevent page url parameters being passed to HTML.Action in ASP.NET MVC 5
The documentation for Action (HtmlHelper, String, String, Object) (or the RouteValueDictionary version) states that "The routeValues parameter is merged with the original route values and overrides them."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-childactionextensions-action(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object)
However, I've realised that this does not play well with optional parameters - say you have something like
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult BigBanner(string bannername, string title = "")

where title is an optional parameter for the controller method which generates a complex banner block. If the title is supplied by the calling page, then all is well and good. If it's omitted, then the intention is that the child action won't render a title. However, if someone crafts a URL with ?title=SomethingBad, then this will be rendered onto the page. At best this allows arbitrary content to be rendered, at worst it's the basis for a XSS attack depending on how the parameters were used.
Clarification/Edit The point here is that ANY optional parameter that is not used in the Html.Action call CAN BE SET BY THE URL - therefore changing the desired behaviour of a page. So there's an infinite variety of possible exploits of this deppending on how those optional parameters are used.
Is there a way to use Html.Action without the merging of the object/routevaluedictionary with the page level parameters to prevent this sort of parameter setting - it seems rather an unsafe default.

"At best this allows arbitrary content to be rendered, at worst it's the basis for a XSS attack" Very true. You should always validate or at the very least restrict how content coming from an external source is rendered.

XSS attacks can't happen if the text is properly escaped.

@Charlieface Agreed- and I don't believe there is any danger of an XSS attack where I've found this issue, however, it does allow arbitrary content to be inserted into a page via a link that can be shared, potentially without the recipient knowing that the page is not as intended.

@phuzi the point is that ChildActionOnly type controller methods are not intended to be  (or atleast I don't think of them as being) accessible from an external source. However, if they have unused optional parameters then those can be set from an external source. Any optional parameter in any controller action. This feels a bit terrifying.

@Andiih, true but this "feature" (if you want to call it that) can help propagate data from the top level page down through multiple levels of child actions/partial views rather than the programmer potentially having to do this themselves. I can gurantee that I have used this myself in the past.

Whether it's safe or not is something that should be mitigated by your application by rendering any string from whatever source in an appropriate way. By default, any string will be rendered safely unless you use Html.Raw() in the view to mitigate the possibility of XSS attacks.

@phuzi its not just about rendering strings. Its that any parameter to any partial can be set from a URL. I've used it deliberatley for things like pagination - however, its just dawned on me that the way modelbinding works means that any unset parameter can be set malliciously from the URL. ANY PARAMETER! Could switch on and off features, detailed views, enable delete, swap betten deep and shallow delete, expose otherwise hidden data, etc. Any feature that you relied on being off by default  can potentially be turned on. So much code to review to find if this is the case.

This is actually quite a useful feature and, by default, mitigated by ASP.NET by escaping the rendered string automatically.
Unless you deliberately go out of the way to shoot yourself in the foot and use HtmlHelper.Raw() then given
?title=<script>alert('hello')</script>

When rendered in the partial view something like
@Model.Title

Will be automatically escaped and safely rendered as
&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;hello&#39;)&lt;/script&gt;

Yes, it might make the page ugly, but it isn't dangerous by default.
There's an answer to "ASP.NET MVC XSS protection" that goes in to more detail.

The point isnt the rendering of a parameter - yes we can make that particular exploit safe(ish). The point is that any optional parameter can be set via the URL : e.g. a component that shows a user profile and has an optional flag to show the details if the profile is viewed by its own user or an admin could have that flag set via the URL So unless there is a way to turn this off optional parameters are very unsafe.
